# Gmail API retrieving Message ID after sending/insert call

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-js-client

Is there a way to get the Message ID after inserting a message via the API's response?

For example, I use the below code to insert the initial message:

```
try:
    message1 = service.users().messages().insert(userId='me', body=temp).execute()
    print(f"{message1['id']} / {message1['threadId']}")
```

In this API call, `id` and `threadId` are the same, a 16 character string.

Next, I insert a reply. I go into Gmail to get the Message ID (`<...@mail.gmail.com>`) and set this up in the next API call as follows:

```
message['subject'] = 'Re: test subject'
message['In-Reply-To'] = '<...@mail.gmail.com>'
message['References'] = '<...@mail.gmail.com>'
encoded_message = urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())
temp = {'raw': encoded_message.decode(), 'labelIds': ['UNREAD'], 'threadId': 'THREAD_ID_FROM_FIRST_CALL'}
try:
    message1 = service.users().messages().insert(userId='me', body=temp).execute()
    print(f"{message1['id']} / {message1['threadId']}")
```

The response here is a different `message1['id']` but the same `message1['threadId']` as above, so it shows up properly threaded in Gmail. But, is there a way to easily get Message ID from the response body? Can I generate it from `message1['id']`? The alternative is to make a second API to find a message by `message1['id']` but I'm trying to avoid that. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot understand about `get Message ID from the response body`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no direct way to retrieve the new `messageId` apart from making a new API call.

This is due to the fact that `messageId` and `threadId` are two different parameters:

- `messageId` corresponding to **the message in the thread**
- `threadId` corresponding to **the thread**

So if you insert a new reply into a thread, the `threadId` will obviously be the same as the one associated to the original message, but the new reply will receive a new id - a `messageId` which is unique and has nothing to do with the `threadId` associated with it.

What you can do instead is to group all the threads by their `threadId`s and based on that, insert a new reply. In this way, you can also easily gather the `messageId`s from that specific thread.

**Reference**

- [Users.threads: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list);
- [Users.threads: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get);
- [Users.messages: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list);
- [Users.messages: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get).

Comment: Thanks. I looked a closer look at the full response body after an insert call and there wasn't anything there, either. So I assume `messageId` is unique and after inserting a message, I do a `messages.get` on the `messageId` I just got and pull the `Message-Id` from the response.